# How to process the emitted event from the component in v-for of Vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm trying to process the emitted the event from the component rendered by the `v-for`.
For example, 
I've made a `combobox` component that emits the event when changing the value.
It emits the event by `this.$emit('item_change', item);`.
I want to process this event for the corresponded user.
In the below code, I want to change the `status` value of the user when changing the value of the `combobox` of `user`.
It gets `item` as parameter when using `v-on:item_change="status_change"`
 [example](https://jsfiddle.net/hr76bntd/48/) 
But it doesn't get the `item` as parameter in `v-on:item_change="status_change(item , user)"` though `combobox` emits the event with `item`, and `status` of `user` keeps the original value.

How could I solve this issue?

[JSFiddle Example](https://jsfiddle.net/hr76bntd/24/)

```
<div id="mainapp">
 <table>
  <thead>
    <th>Name</th><th>Status</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr v-for="user in users">
      <td>{{user.name}}</td>
      <td><combobox v-bind:default="user.status" v-bind:data="status_codes" v-on:item_change="status_change(item, user)"></combobox></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

JS code

```
var combobox = Vue.component('combobox', {
  data: function () {
    return {
      selected_item:{title:'Select', value:-1},
      visible:false
    }
  },
  props:['data','default','symbol'],
  template: `
    <div class="combobox">
      <span class="symbol" v-if="!symbol">
        <i class="fa fa-chevron-down" aria-hidden="true"  ></i>
      </span>
      <span class="main" v-on:click="toggleVisible">{{selected_item.title}}</span>
      <ul class="combodata" v-if="visible">
        <li class="item" v-for="item in data" v-on:click="select(item)">{{item.title}}</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  `,
  created:function(){
    if(this.data.length>0){
      if(this.default == null || this.default == undefined || this.default =='') this.default=0;
      this.selected_item = this.data[this.default];
    }
  },
  methods:{
    toggleVisible:function(){
      this.visible = !this.visible;
    },
    select:function(item){
      if(this.selected_item != item){
        this.selected_item= item;
        this.$emit('item_change', item);
      }
      this.visible = false;
    }
  }
});

var app=new Vue({
  el:"#mainapp",
  data:{
     status_codes:[{title:'Inactive', value:0},{title:'Active', value:1}],
     users:[{name:'Andrew', status:1},{name:'Jackson', status:0},{name:'Tom', status:1}]
  },
  methods:{
     status_change:function(item,user){  //This gets only the parameter from the event. How could I pass the additional parameters to this function?
        console.log(item,user);
        try{
          user.status = item.value;
        }catch(e){ console.log}
     }
  }
});
```

Comment: What about to pass `index` of `user` to the component ?

Comment: @talent_developer Isn't there any other resolutions? And then it couldn't be used globally. I think so.

Comment: finding out the solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `$event` to your `status_change` handler instead of `item`

```html
<div id="mainapp">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Status</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr v-for="user in users">
                <td>{{user.name}}</td>
                <td>
                    <combobox v-bind:default="user.status" v-bind:data="status_codes" v-on:item_change="status_change($event, user)"></combobox>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emf1u4jd/1/)

> [See the Vue docs here about event handling](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html):
> Sometimes we also need to access the original DOM event in an inline statement handler. You can pass it into a method using the special $event variable

Answer (score 4):

Use `$event`

What you need is actually `v-on:item_change="status_change($event , user)"`.

When you do `this.$emit('item_change', whatever);`, `whatever` will become `$event` in the event listener.

https://jsfiddle.net/jacobgoh101/bLsw085r/1/

Answer (score 1):

Try passing parameters to your function like this:

```
v-on:item_change="status_change(item, user)"
```

And in your function declaration, specify the parameters:

```
status_change: function (item, user) {
   console.log(item, user);
}
```